# Countif Formula with Multiple Criteria - Text and Date in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

In my workbook I have a summary page that pulls from the worksheets(Active, Pending and Closed) within the workbook.  Those worksheets are linked to other workbooks.  On the summary page, I want to obtain how many items are overdue on the Active worksheet based on if the date is prior to today's date. 
Active Worksheet in Column C is the Employee's Name and in Column H is Due Date.  I tried the following formula requesting the overdue information for an employee named Amy:

```
=COUNTIFS(Active!C:C,"Amy",Active!H:H,"<TODAY()")
```

This provides an incorrect answer.  It returns zero, instead of the correct number.  Any assistance in this matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(C:C,"Amy",H:H,"<"&NOW())` will do the trick. Flags everything with a date lower than todays date for employee "Amy".

Comment: `TODAY()` is probably better than `NOW()` if you want to exclude today's data.

Comment: It is still coming back with zero, when it should be 3.  This is the formula that I used: =COUNTIFS(Active!C:C,"Amy",Active!H:H,"<"TODAY())

Comment: try `=COUNTIFS(Active!C:C,"Amy",Active!H:H,"<"&TODAY())` put `&` between `"<"` and `TODAY()`

Comment: I tried it, and it still is showing zero as the answer.  =COUNTIFS(Active!C:C,"Amy",Active!H:H,"<"&TODAY())

Comment: how about sharing some sample data or share your sample workbook via google drive or one drive so we can look into the issue? ps. please use @name to address me (or other user) otherwise we may miss out your reply.